# Routing to /public and index.php in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP application based on Slim framework with static files in `/public` directory and following `.htacces` file:

```
# URL routing
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

When I trying to access /index.php Apache returns it directly, but I want it to be passed to be rewritten to index.php (which will return 404 not found). How can I do it?

If I try to remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`:

```
# URL routing
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Apache returns me "Internal server error". How can I get it done?

Upd: my project structure

```
www/
├── app/
├── cache/
├── public/
│   ├── css/
│   ├── img/
│   └── js/
├── vendor/
├── views/
└── index.php
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? My setup is almost identical but I can't get it to work either.

Answer (score 1):

Your RewriteRules are a mess.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

What you are telling Apache there is "if DOCUMENT_ROOT/public%{REQUEST_URI} is a file". However, in your set-up, DOCUMENT_ROOT will already be public/. This is the source of your mess.

Consider this instead:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /public/$1 [L]

 RewriteRule ^$ ./index.php [QSA,L]
```

Apache already makes the filename translation for you, the one you are trying to do using DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: I tried to change my Apache site configuration: `DocumentRoot /home/user/www/public`, `<Directory /home/user/www> ... </Directory>` and use your .htaccess, but it returns Internal server error when I try to access `/`. See update about my project structure.

Comment: This should be a bit more streamlined. @therussianphysicist

Comment: Internal server error again: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: @therussianphysicist: Do you happen to have any other rewrite rules before that that are not `[L]` (last) in the file?

Answer (score -1):

Best thing to do is to delete the .HTACCESS file or edit it in Your Server ROOT with

DirectoryIndex public_html www html

Comment: But how can it help me?
I just want to show static files from `~/www/public` if them exist in it and redirect other requests to `~/www/index.php`.